# How do you call a jquery-ui dialog when also using jquery-easyui?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

I'm trying to use jEasyUI and jQueryUI on a web page. I would like to use the easyui ribbon plugin found here http://www.jeasyui.com/extension/ribbon.php as well as standard jQuery dialogs. It seems that the jquery-easyui library overrides the standard jquery-ui $.dialog method with its own version. Is it possible to use jquery-ui and jquery-easyui at the same time and choose which objects you want from either library?

I've tried simply calling the libraries easyui first and jquery-ui second, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

**EDIT TO ADD EXAMPLE CODE**

The desired result is I want to add a button to the dialog toolbar, and I need handles on the open and close events for the dialog. Commenting out the easyui head lines reverts to using jqueryui, but I of course can't use the extra easyui stuff I want access to.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">


        <script src="vendor/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

        <script src="vendor/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>

        <!-- jquery-easyui stuff -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/jquery-easyui-1.4.3/themes/default/easyui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/jquery-easyui-1.4.3/themes/icon.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/jquery-easyui-1.4.3/demo/demo.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery-easyui-1.4.3/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>

        <!-- jquery-easyui stuff -->

        <link href="vendor/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body>


        <div id="DialogDrawer" style="display:none;">
            <div id="PrintingHolderDiv">
                <div>
                    <label>Paper Size:</label>
                    <select id="PrintPageSize" onchange="PrintPaperSizeSelected()">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="A4">8.5" x 11" </option>
                        <option value="A3" selected>11" x 17" </option>
                        <option value="Plotter18">18" plotter </option>
                        <option value="Plotter24">24" plotter </option>
                        <option value="Plotter36">36" plotter </option>
                        <option value="Custom">Custom </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="PrintPaperWidthDiv" class="block">
                    <label>Paper Width</label>
                    <input id="PrintPageWidth" type="number" value="17" oninput="PrintPageSizeUpdated();"></input>
                </div>
                <div id="PrintPaperHeightDiv" class="block">
                    <label>Paper Height</label>
                    <input id="PrintPageHeight" type="number" value="11" oninput="PrintPageSizeUpdated();"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script>
            function PopupDialog(divID, dialogTitle, dialogWidth, dialogHeight){
                // This function makes a dialog for the specified the specified dialog out of the ribbon

                // Open the dialog and run the callback function
                var q = $('#' + divID + 'HolderDiv').dialog({
                    // modal:true,
                    title: dialogTitle,
                    width: dialogWidth,
                    height: dialogHeight,
                      open: function(event, ui){

                        //// THIS EVENT ISN'T HIT WITH EasyUI dialog

                        //// THIS CODE WORKS WITH THE jquery-ui dialog

                        // Add the pop-out icon next to the close button in the dialog toolbar
                        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").append("<img id='" + divID + "_NewWindowPopupImg' class='ui-icon ui-icon-help' src='Images/PopOut.png' style='padding-right: 40px; cursor:pointer;' title='Open sidebar in new window'>");



                        $('#' + divID + '_NewWindowPopupImg').click(
                            // Closure for this window
                            function(){ 
                                // do stuff...
                            }
                        );

                      },
                      close: function(event, ui) {

                        //// THIS EVENT ISN'T HIT WITH EasyUI dialog

                        $(this).dialog('destroy');
                      }
                });



            }

            window.onload = function(){
                PopupDialog('Printing', 'Print', 300, 400);
            }
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: How about a specific example? Otherwise you are likely to get down voted or get generic answers.

Comment: Why not just use the jquery-easyui dialog?  I think you're going to encounter problems trying to use both libraries.

Comment: @B2K: thanks for the advice. I added an example. I'm not proficient enough in jsfiddle to set up a one-click "here's my issue", so here's the best I've got at the moment.

Comment: @Maulzal: Mostly the reason for using the jquery dialogs is so I can get at the open/close events and be able to futz with the dialog toolbar. If it's possible to do these things easily with easyui then I would consider using its dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be not possible to fix this issue. You just have to use the dialog offered by jquery-easyui and avoid using jquery-ui if you are already using jquery-easyui. This is a fiddle created by someone else:`e` http://jsfiddle.net/vmDP8/11/